# Cocoa: Confused by #define in code?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor

I was going through some code that I downloaded off the internet ([Got it here](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/))

I am confused with this line of code... What exactly is it doing?

```
#define N_RANDOM_WORDS (sizeof(randomWords)/sizeof(NSString *))
```

Here is the array of "randomWords":

```
static NSString *randomWords[] = {
@"Hello",
@"World",
@"Some",
@"Random",
@"Words",
@"Blarg",
@"Poop",
@"Something",
@"Zoom zoom",
@"Beeeep",
};
```

Comment: Questions are much more useful to others if you give them clear, descriptive titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof(randomWords)` gives the number of bytes taken up by the array. Each element of the array is an `NSString` pointer. `sizeof(NSString*)` gives the size of each pointer. So dividing the total size by the size of each element gives the number of elements.

`N_RANDOM_WORDS` is a macro being defined. Wherever it is used, the expression `sizeof(randomWords)/sizeof(NSString*)` will be inserted in its place by the preprocessor. This is usually how constants are defined in C or Objective C.

For more information on macros in C (and Objective C), [here's a nice tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html).

Comment: I get it. But just to be sure, if I was to do this: "#define NSLOG_IT (NSLOG @"logging")" And then in my code, i called NSLOG_IT, It would log out "logging"?

Comment: I think you would want to write it as '#define NSLOG_IT NSLog(@"logging")'. You could then write a statement 'NSLOG_IT;' and it would print "logging" like you say.

Comment: One more question. Your saying by doing this, it gives the number of elements. Couldnt you have done something like [randomWords count]?

Comment: Yes, [randomWords count] would be the right way to do it if you had an NSArray. However, what you have above is a regular old-fashioned C array. Since it is not an Objective C object, it cannot receive messages like count.

Answer (score 1):

One `NSString*` takes `sizeof(NSString*)` bytes.  The size of `randomWords` is `N * sizeof(NSString)`.  So solving for `N`, you get `N = sizeof(randomWords)/sizeof(NSString *)`.